# Proving Fatou's Lemma using the limit inequalities of measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space.

Let $\left(A_i\right)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathcal A$.

Then it holds that:
$$
\mu\left(\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{A_n}\right)\le\ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\mu\left(A_n\right)}\tag{1}
$$
Is further $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i\right)<\infty$, then it also holds that
$$
\mu\left(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{A_n}\right)\geq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\mu\left(A_n\right)} \tag{2}
$$
I want to use (1) and (2) to prove the generalized Fatou's Lemma:

> Let
> $\left(f_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of ($\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(\bar{\mathbb R})$)-measurable functions $f_n:\Omega\to[0,\infty]$.
>
> If there exists an integrable $f:\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ such that $\int_\Omega f \, d\mu<\infty$ and $\forall n: \quad f_n\le f$, then we have
>
> $$ \int_{\Omega}\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n}}\, d\mu \le\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int_{\Omega} f_n}}\, d\mu 
> \le\lim{\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int_{\Omega} f_n}}\, d\mu
> \le
> \int_{\Omega}\lim{\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n}}\, d\mu  
> \tag{3}$$

The intuitive approach seems to be to construct a pointwise convergent sequence of simple functions for each $f_n$. However, both constructing the sequence, as well as arguing that we can later on swap the limit of the sequence with the limit inferior seem rather technical.

---

Here is an approach I tried using the common approximation of a function by simple functions:

Let $g≔\liminf_{n→∞}f_n$, and
$$
g_n\left(x\right)≔n⋅\mathbb{1}_{g^{-1}[n,∞)}(x)+\sum_{j=0}^{n⋅2n-1} \frac{j}{2^n} \mathbb{1}_{ g^{-1}([\frac j{2^n},\frac{j+1}{2^n}))}(x)
$$

Since $f_n\geq0$, we have that $\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n}}\geq0$, and by construction then $\left(g_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a monotonously increasing sequence that is pointwise convergent against $g$.

Therefore we have:
$$
\int_{\Omega}\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n}}d\mu=\int_{\Omega}\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{g_k}d\mu
$$
Using monotonous convergence:
$$
=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega} g_kd\mu
$$
Substituting in $g_k$:
$$
=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega}{k\cdot\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left[k,\infty\right)\right)}+\sum_{j=0}^{k\cdot2^k-1}{\frac{j}{2^k}\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right)\right)}}}d\mu
$$

Here, I now would like to go  from
$\mathbb{1}_{({\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n}}})^{-1}\left(\left[...\right)\right)}$
to
$\mathbb{1}_{{\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\big(f_n^{-1}}}\left(\left[...\right)\right)\big)}$

But since $[...)$ isn't a compact interval, there is no set inclusion between the first and second indicator sets.

Comment: Note that $\boldsymbol{1}_{\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n} = \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \boldsymbol{1}_{A_n}$, with $\boldsymbol{1}_A$ being the indicator function for the set $A$ (of course the same holds for the limes superior). Might this help?

Comment: @stange The problem with any partition of $\Omega$ into sets $A_n$ is that as far as I can see I, I need to set $A_n:=(\liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n)^{-1}(B_n)$ (for the e.g. the first inequality). If I then want to pull the limit inferior out of the preimage, I need that $B_n$ is compact, but I don't think such a partition that all $B_n$ are compact, exists

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to know how to prove this, or how to prove it using the simple approximation theorem

Comment: @FShrike As long as it uses (1) and (2), I'm happy with both, though I'd prefer a full solution since I've tried a few times and each try ended in a dead end so far

Comment: Hmm. There are lots of proofs of the Fatou lemma on this site, I fear that if I post a proof it will be a duplicate of some kind

Comment: @FShrike The common proof of the lemma goes using the definition of $\liminf$ as $\sup\inf$, i.e. it uses the interpretation of the limit inferior for sequences. What I want is instead the methodology by first turning the sequence of functions into a sequence of sets and then using the set variants of $\lim\sup$. I believe that this method will help me in later proofs

Answer (score 1):

The following approach isn't complete, but looks like it should work, so I'll leave it here for completeness. However, it wasn't as insightful as I had hoped.

By using the common approximation with left-half-open intervals instead of my approach, we obtain:
$$
=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega}
{k\cdot\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left(k,\infty\right)\right)}
+
\sum_{j=0}^{k\cdot2^k-1}
{\frac{j}{2^k}\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right]\right)}}}
d\mu\tag{10}
$$

Since the preimage maintains disjointness, we have:

$$
\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\infty\right)\right)}
=
\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right]\cup(\frac {j+1} {2^k},\infty)\right)}
=
\mathbb{1}_{\left({\ g}^{-1}\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right]\cup g^{-1}(\frac {j+1} {2^k},\infty)\right)}
=
\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right]}
+
\mathbb{1}_{g^{-1}(\frac {j+1} {2^k},\infty)}
$$

Summarized:
$$
\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right]}
=
\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\infty\right)}
-
\mathbb{1}_{g^{-1}(\frac {j+1} {2^k},\infty)}
$$

Therefore, we can replace all half-open intervals in the sum in my approach by open intervals. Furthermore, for $x\in\mathbb R$ the following set inclusion holds:
$$
\left(\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n}}\right)^{-1}\left(x,\infty\right)\subseteq\lim{\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(f_n^{-1}\left(x,\infty\right)\right)}}
$$

So continuing from (10):
$$
(10)=
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega}
k\cdot\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left(k,\infty\right)\right)}
+
\sum_{j=0}^{k\cdot2^k-1}{\frac{j}{2^k}
\left(\mathbb{1}_{{\ g}^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\infty\right)\right)}
-
\mathbb{1}_{g^{-1}(\frac{j+1}{2^k},\infty)
}\right)}d\mu
\\\le
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega}
k\cdot
\mathbb{1}_{
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n^{-1}
((k,\infty))}
+
\sum_{j=0}^{k\cdot2^k-1}{\frac{j}{2^k}
\left(\mathbb{1}_{\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{j}{2^k},\infty\right)\right)}
-
\mathbb{1}_{\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n^{-1}(\frac{j+1}{2^k},\infty)
}\right)}d\mu
$$
We can now use linearity of the integral, and simplify each integral to  the function value of the measure, then apply (1), and then use linearity of the limit inferiors.

However, way simpler is pulling out the limit inferior
$$
=
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{n\to\infty}
k\cdot
\mathbb{1}_{f_n^{-1}((k,\infty))}
+
\sum_{j=0}^{k\cdot2^k-1}{\frac{j}{2^k}
\left(\mathbb{1}_{{\ f_n}^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right)\right)}
-
\mathbb{1}_{f_n^{-1}(-\infty,\frac j {2^k})
}\right)}d\mu
$$
and once again using monotone convergence
$$
=
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}
k\cdot
\mathbb{1}_{f_n^{-1}((k,\infty))}
+
\sum_{j=0}^{k\cdot2^k-1}{\frac{j}{2^k}
\left(\mathbb{1}_{{\ f_n}^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,\frac{j+1}{2^k}\right)\right)}
-
\mathbb{1}_{f_n^{-1}(-\infty,\frac j {2^k})
}\right)}d\mu
$$

Now, all that's left to show the first inequality is to show that we can swap limit and limit inferior.